# Question about closest, submit and AJAX PUT requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having trouble stopping form submission. Here's the html (I'm using  EJS by the way) for context:

```
<form class="edit-form" id="edit-review-form<%= review._id %>" action="/products/<%= product._id %>/reviews/<%= review._id %>" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled value="<%= currentUser.username %>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="review[subject]" value="<%= review.subject %>" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="review[rating]" id="rating" class="rating" value="<%=review.rating %>" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="review[text]" placeholder="<%= review.text %>" form="edit-review-form<%= review._id %>" rows="5" cols="70"><%= review.text %></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
</div>
<button class="reviewButton btn-edit-submit">Edit</button>
```

And here's my AJAX along with a script that has comments in between the lines explaining

```
$(".edit-form").submit(function (event) { // Why does this not? On the developers console this does selects the form, but doesn't stops it from submitting...
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = $(this).serialize();
    let formAction = $(this).attr("action");
    // console.log(formData);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": $("#_csrf").val()}
    });
    $.ajax({
        context: this, /* setting context for ajax callbacks*/
        url: formAction,
        data: formData,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
        if (data) {
            console.log("Success! = " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log("Something went wrong: " + data.responseText);
    });
    return false;
});

var editReviews = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-edit-submit');
$('.collapse').on("shown.bs.collapse", function(){
 //triggers when div is collapse
    console.log("collapsed in"); // Works after collapse is finished
    for (var i = 0; i < editReviews.length; i++) {
        editReviews[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { // editReviews works in the dev console and every button is selected
            event.preventDefault();
            // alert("clicked"); // This alert is working,
            // PUT Request form
            this.closest("form").submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Also, if I submit the form from the terminal, it does NOT submits the form triggering the POST error (since it's actually a put request) but the AJAX goes through, if I click the button it submits me and launches the error. Any ideas?

EDIT: Also tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < editReviews.length; i++) {
    editReviews[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { // editReviews works in the dev console and every button is selected
        event.preventDefault();
        // alert("clicked"); // This alert is working,
        // PUT Request form
        this.closest("form").submit();
    });
}
```

But it didn't work either.

I feel like I also need to mention that the reason I'm using the .closest selector is that there are multiple forms like that in the view file.

EDIT: Thanks Basmar, tried your suggestion:

```
var submitEditForm = function(form) {
    form.submit(function (event) { // Why does this not? On the developers console this does selects the form, but doesn't stops it from submitting...
        // console.log(this);
        let formData = $(this).serialize();
        let formAction = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": $("#_csrf").val()}
        });
        $.ajax({
            context: this, /* setting context for ajax callbacks*/
            url: formAction,
            data: formData,
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "json"
            })
            .done(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("Success! = " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
            }).fail(function(data) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + data.responseText);
        });
    });
}

var editReviews = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-edit-submit');
for (var i = 0; i < editReviews.length; i++) {
    editReviews[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { // editReviews works in the dev console and every button is selected
        event.preventDefault();
        // alert("clicked"); // This alert is working,
        // PUT Request form
        var form = this.closest("form");
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            submitEditForm(form);
        });
    });
}
```

It stops it from submitting but the AJAX request won't go through either, did I do it wrong?

Also, if I submit the form without actually using .closest() it does submits through the POST route but the thing is that it submits the first form.edit-form since I'm kind of hardcoding it.

Comment: I feel like I also need to mention that I'm using .closest selector since there are multiple forms like that in the view file.

Comment: If you think you need to mention it, it should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Calling the `.submit()` method of a form is not an event, so the jQuery event handler is not invoked. It would be better if you used jQuery consistently throughout. Calling the jQuery `.submit()` method will run the jQuery handlers.

Comment: It's also more confusing when you mix jQuery and plain JS. It took me several readings to realize that this is JS `.closest()`, not jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It really is confusing. Is there a closest() method in jQuery? Or do you think this would actually work with plain JS (with a .submit equivalent) + the AJAX bit?

Comment: Extract the code that does the AJAX submission into a named function that takes the form as an argument. Call it from the click handler and the submit handler.

Comment: Just did that, more details in the question because of the char limit in the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `form.submit()` in `submitEditForm`, you should just execute the AJAX code.

Also, the click listener for the submit buttons should just call `submitEditForm()`, not add a submit handler for the form (it's almost always wrong to add an event listener inside another listener -- every time you click you add another listener, and the submit handler doesn't work until you submit after the first click).

```
var submitEditForm = function(form) {

  // console.log(this);
  let formData = $(form).serialize();
  let formAction = $(form).attr("action");
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": $("#_csrf").val()
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
      context: form,
      /* setting context for ajax callbacks*/
      url: formAction,
      data: formData,
      type: "PUT",
      dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      if (data) {
        console.log("Success! = " + JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }).fail(function(data) {
      console.log("Something went wrong: " + data.responseText);
    });
};

$(".edit-form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  submitEditForm(this);
});

var editReviews = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-edit-submit');
for (var i = 0; i < editReviews.length; i++) {
  editReviews[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { // editReviews works in the dev console and every button is selected
    event.preventDefault();
    // alert("clicked"); // This alert is working,
    // PUT Request form
    var form = this.closest("form");
    submitEditForm(form);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't belive form.submit() inside the AJAX was messing everything so much. I'll remember not to nest event listeners again and not to actually submit the forms inside the AJAX functions!